# Como autenticar em um site via servidor?

Tags: .net, lado-do-servidor, cliente-servidor, oauth

Existe uma área de login nesse website "https://id.nintendo.net/login" e gostaria de saber se é possível logar nele via .NET ou via cliente utilizando post ou algo do tipo.

Comment: O que realmente você precisa fazer além de autenticar? Especifique melhor sua pergunta.

Comment: Depois de autenticar precisaria "baixar" o html para o servidor (estou desenvolvendo uma API), pois precisaria das informações que estão depois da área de login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa é desenvolver um *web crawler*.

Você pode desenvolver um crawler de duas maneiras diferentes:

- Com uma solução baseada em webkit (a engine de navegadores como o Chrome, Safari e Opera), como o `CasperJS`, que é feito em cima do `PhantomJS`. Soluções desse tipo costumam emular bem o que um navegador "de verdade" faz, como executar JavaScript, requisições, AJAX, baixar imagens, etc. Normalmente essas soluções são desenvolvidas em JavaScript.
- Emulando requisições HTTP em linguagens de programação como PHP, .Net, Java, etc. O problema nesse caso é que você teria de emular cada aspecto de uma navegação de verdade e acaba sendo bem mais trabalhoso – entretanto, o seu controle das informações é maior.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de fazer pelo lado do servidor?

Comment: @luckakashi ambas são no lado do servidor :)